How to concatenate full form and abbreviation in labels using Turtle syntax?
I am working on a .ttl file and I want to incorporate abbreviations into the ontology. Some "things" in my knowledge graph have abbreviations derived from a full form. I want the label of those things (i.e., instances) to be a concatenation of their full form and then their abbreviation in parentheses.
Example:
For an instance representing the term "National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)", I want the label to be "National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)".
My current RDF data in Turtle syntax:
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

ex:NASA
    a ex:Organization ;
    rdfs:label <what should go here?>
    ex:fullForm "National Aeronautics and Space Administration" ;
    ex:abbreviation "NASA" .

Question:
Is it possible to achieve this concatenation directly within Turtle syntax, or should I use a different approach such as SPARQL? If so, how can I accomplish this?

That is not possible with (and not the purpose of) Turtle.
SPARQL is the right choice, e.g.:
INSERT {

  ?org rdfs:label ?label .

}
WHERE {

  ?org a ex:Organization ;
       ex:fullForm ?fullForm ;
       ex:abbreviation ?abbreviation .

  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?org rdfs:label [] . } # if you don’t want to do this for organizations which already have a label

  BIND( CONCAT( ?fullForm, " (", ?abbreviation, ")" ) AS ?label )

}

There are different ways how to handle the involved named graphs (USING, GRAPH {}, WITH, …). See https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert for the specification.
